# Permutation Cycle

Tags: java, permutation

This is my code.  I have 1 error. Please help me.

```
Try this input:
8 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

..........................................................................................

```
import java.io.*;

public class permutation
{
    public static void main (String []args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(    System.in) );
        String n="";
        int parsen=0, parsenum=0;
        System.out.println(n);
        n = dataIn.readLine();
        parsen=Integer.parseInt(n);
        String num[]= new String [1000];
        int visited[]=new int [1000];
        int vindex[]=new int [2000];
        int a=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=parsen;i++){
            num[i-1]=dataIn.readLine();
            parsenum=Integer.parseInt(num[i-1]);
        }
        int t_visited=0, cycles=0, start=0, index=0;

        while(t_visited<parsen)
        {
            for(int i=1; i<=parsen;i++)
            {
                if(visited[i]==0)
                {
                    vindex[start]=i;
                    visited[i]=1;
                    t_visited++;
                    index=start;
                    break;
                }
            }
            while(true)
            {
                index++;
                vindex[index]=parsenum[vindex[index-1]];

                if(vindex[index]==vindex[start])
                    break;
                visited[vindex[index]]=1;
                t_visited++;

                vindex[++index]=0;
                start=index+1;
                cycles++;
            }
            System.out.println(cycles+vindex[0]);
            for(int i=0;i<(parsen+2*cycles);i++)
            {
                if(vindex[i]==0)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }else{
                    System.out.println(vindex[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Another code:
working but wrong output. help pls...i declare num as an integer.

```
import java.io.*;

public class permutation
{
public static void main (String []args) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader dataIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(     System.in) );
    String n="";
    int parsen=0;
    System.out.println(n);
    n = dataIn.readLine();
    parsen=Integer.parseInt(n);
    int num[]= new int [1000];
    int visited[]=new int [1000];
    int vindex[]=new int [2000];
    int a=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=parsen;i++){
        num[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    }
        int t_visited=0, cycles=0, start=0, index=0;

    while(t_visited<parsen)
    {
        for(int b=1; b<=parsen;b++)
        {
            if(visited[b]==0)
            {
                vindex[start]=b;
                visited[b]=1;
                t_visited++;
                index=start;
                break;
            }
        }
        while(true)
        {
            index++;
            vindex[index]=num[vindex[index-1]];

        if(vindex[index]==vindex[start])
            break;
        visited[vindex[index]]=1;
        t_visited++;

        vindex[++index]=0;
        start=index+1;
        cycles++;
        }
        System.out.println(cycles+vindex[0]);
        for(int c=0;c<(parsen+2*cycles);c++)
        {
            if(vindex[c]==0)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }else{
                System.out.print(vindex[c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

the output must be

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5 
6 6
7 7
8 8
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error said:
permutation.java:39: error: array required, but int found
                                vindex[index]=parsenum[vindex[index-1]];
                                                      ^
1 error

Comment: parsenum isn't an array.

Comment: parsenum isn't an array but an int. - did you debug this code?

Comment: Please, edit your question to add the relevant information to it. That is, add the specific error you get when you run this program in the question.

Answer (score 2):

`parsenum` is an `int` - but you use it as if it were an array: `parsenum[vindex[index-1]]`. That can't work.

Comment: ahh..so when i put the input which is 8 it will say that 8[vindex[index-1]]..which is wrong..instead of putting parsenum, what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring `int parsenum=0;` you will have to declare `int parsenum[10];` where `10` will be the size of your array.

Comment: `parsen-1` should be an appropriate length

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the code.. How did you realize that?

Comment: First `for` loop only runs for a max of parsen-1 if I'm correct. May be slightly off though.

Comment: This line `vindex[index]=parsenum[vindex[index-1]];` is confusing me.